# How to make an Python subclass uncallable

Tags: python

How do you "disable" the `__call__` method on a subclass so the following would be true:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        object.__setattr__(self, '__call__', None)

>>> c = Child()
>>> callable(c)
False
```

This and other ways of trying to set `__call__` to some non-callable value still result in the child appearing as callable.

Comment: This begs the question though, is it a good idea to break the interface of a parent class in a child class?

Comment: `callable(obj)` checks `hasattr(obj, '__call__')`; I don't think there's any way you can make `Child` appear to not have the attribute, as that would break inheritance.

Comment: Would it work to `del` the `__call__` reference?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you can't do that: `AttributeError: __call__` on the class, `'Child' object attribute '__call__' is read-only` on the instance

Comment: You could write a wrapper for the class but then `isinstance` would fail.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: if the Child-class has no attribute `__call__`, it is looked up in the parent class.

Comment: Maybe you could have the child define its own `__call__` to mask the parent's, and define it in a way that makes it look uncallable?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that would work to prevent calling *in practice*, but **won't** affect the result of `callable`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it looks callable if it's there. So if it's there, there's nothing it could be such that it wouldn't look callable.

Comment: Why do you want the class to be uncallable?

Comment: So, it'll appear callable as long as there's a `__call__` somewhere, and `__call__` can't be taken out? Sounds a bit intractable.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, In general, I agree, this is usually not what you want to do. In my case, I'm working with a peak.CallbackProxy object that does a pretty good job almost seamlessly wrapping the object. The only caveat is that the proxy appears callable even if the object isn't, which can alter that way other code treats it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. As jonrsharpe points out, there's no way to make `Child` appear to not have the attribute, and that's what `callable(Child())` relies on to produce its answer. Even making it a descriptor that raises `AttributeError` won't work, per this bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue23990 . A python 2 example:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...     def __call__(self): pass
... 
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     __call__ = property()
...
>>> c = Child()
>>> c()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: unreadable attribute
>>> c.__call__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: unreadable attribute
>>> callable(c)
True
```

This is because `callable(...)` doesn't act out the descriptor protocol. Actually calling the object, or accessing a `__call__` attribute, involves retrieving the method even if it's behind a property, through the normal descriptor protocol. But `callable(...)` doesn't bother going that far, if it finds anything at all it is satisfied, and every subclass of Parent will have *something* for `__call__` -- either an attribute in a subclass, or the definition from `Parent`.

So while you can make actually calling the instance fail with any exception you want, you can't ever make `callable(some_instance_of_parent)` return False.

Comment: It might be useful to bring more of the logic into the answer, noting that `__call__ = property()` would make `hasattr(Child(), '__call__')` return `False`, but not affect `callable` as it checks the class, not the instance, for the a attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Done so. How's it look?

Comment: Isn't the question actually asking how to make *instances* of a subclass uncallable, not how to make a class itself uncallable?

Comment: @user2357112 yes, but `callable` looks for `__call__` *on the class*, not the instance

Comment: @jonrsharpe: All the example code and descriptions in this answer are about making the class itself uncallable. `callable(Child)`, `callable(Class)`, `callable(someclass)`, etc., rather than `callable(Child())` or `callable(Class())`.

Comment: @user2357112 Oops. Yes. I misread drastically. Fixed.

The answer remains the same, but some wording differs, and example code changes. (Basically my answer talked about the specific case of where Parent = type.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to change the public interface of the class so radically from the parent to the base.

As pointed out elsewhere, you *cant* uninherit `__call__`.  If you really need to mix in callable and non callable classes you should use another test (adding a class attribute) or simply making it safe to call the variants with no functionality.

To do the latter, You could override the `__call__` to raise `NotImplemented` (or better, a custom exception of your own) if for some reason you wanted to mix a non-callable class in with the callable variants:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print "called"

class Child (Parent):
    def __call__(self):
        raise NotACallableInstanceException()

for child_or_parent in list_of_children_and_parents():
   try:  
      child_or_parent()
   except NotACallableInstanceException:
      pass
```

Or, just override call with pass:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print "called"

class Child (Parent):
    def __call__(self):
        pass
```

Which will still be callable but just be a nullop.

Comment: Per the comments, none of this affects the result of `callable`